# web application development with j2me

Tags: javascript, web-applications, java-me

The main reason I'd like to use j2me is that one of its main advantages is that it can access the phone's resources through its various APIs. However, due to newer phones having web browsers like Safari, Opera, and Windows IE, it would be advantageous to build a web application so a user wouldn't have to download some software onto their phone. Is there a way I could build a web application that can also acquire resource information about the phone? Or maybe have j2me converted to Javascript (if that's even possible)?

Comment: [WebVM](http://wiki.webvm.net/)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a link that would send an SMS, but other than that, there's no cross-platform api for accessing phone internals from browser, as far as I know.

So, if you've got to access phone's resources, you'll have to write a real app.

Answer (score 0):

The webkit engine on recent Series60 phones has been given access to at least some phone resources.

Nokai calls it Web Runtime or WRT.

http://www.forum.nokia.com/Resources_and_Information/Documentation/